# Managing large amount of data in OpenCL raytracing

Tags: graphics, opencl, gpgpu, raytracing, large-data

I've bounced into a issue with OpenCL. I'm currently writing a raytracer in CL. The issue I met is that I have a lot of vertexes and modifying them is super inefficient.

This is how my current kernel looks.

```c
__kernel void raytraceTheme(__global int* width, __global int*
    height, __global Triangle* triangles, __global int* triangleCount,
    __global float4* renderBuffer);
```

Let's say that I have 100K triangles and it takes around 98MB of RAM in my GPU. To update/delete/add some vertexes I have to literally release all the vertex data on OpenCL, modify them in CPU than upload all of them again. This is a ridiculously slow process.

The solution I came up to fix this without limiting how much triangles I can have; is to chunk up my data and create a pointer array so I could access them while raytracing. In case of running out of space in triangleStorage I could simply re-allocate one(which won't take too long anyway). Making something like the following.

```c
__kernel void uploadTriangle(__global Triangle** triangleStorage, 
    __global Triangle* triangle, __global int* index)
{
    triangleStorage[index] = triangle;
}
__kernel void raytraceTheme(__global Triangle** triangleStorage,
    , __global int* chunkNum......)
```

But after some googling and experiments, I found that OpenCL does not support double pointer in kernel arguments. I'm stuck. I have no idea how could I bypass this.

Comment: Basically find a way so I could update a lot of data in OpenCL really fast without limiting the maximum amound of data I can upload to my OpenCL device.

Comment: I don't think this is a xy-problem since I'm giving up both  X and Y. They both fail.

Comment: Why do you have to change these triangles? I don't recall why an raytracer would need to do that, unless you're writing an interactive raytracer that renders as the model is being created.

Comment: Yes, it is a raytracer with the feature of changing stuff on scence dynamically.

Comment: I think you would have to send some kind of delta to the GPU, no the whole scene again. Sending the whole scene will strain the PCI express bus. Try to split your vertex data into objects or groups and send only the group that is being changed.

Comment: Unforchantly, I can't.(and this is why I'm here asking for help)
As we all know. To chunk a huge array of data into smaller ones, we need a double pointer(pointer to pointer) to achieve this. However double pointers arn't supported in OpenCL. I need a way to upload chunked data without double pointers. But.... I can't come up with one.

Comment: You can't use *any* pointers with OpenCL because they point to host memory addresses, you must copy the data to your devices.

I believe you can try using *offset* parameter of the `clEnqueueWriteBuffer` function to only copy part of your data. You can split your vertex data into "object zones" and then have a second data structure only storing when one object start and finishes (indexes).

Comment: I forgot to mention you can also try to use the new features available on OpenCL 2.0, such as shared virtual memory, I didn't take a look at the API though. And I don't know how good is the driver support to 2.0. See this article from AMD that might be helpful http://developer.amd.com/community/blog/2014/10/24/opencl-2-shared-virtual-memory/

Comment: As we know. whenever I call `clSetKernelArg`, it passes a pointer to the memory where the argument is stored. So, the only way I'ld access multiple 'buffers' to by passing a double pointer which points to somewhere stores an array of these 'pointer' which points to individual buffers. But this is not allowed in OpenCL. (not sure about 2.0 but definitely in 1.2)

Comment: I would really like to use some new feature of OpenCL 2.0. But I need my code be capable to run on Nvidia devices too. Which I don't think they will make CL 2.0 available on their device any time too soon. Especially I'm using Linux.